# C# An unexpected 'StartObject' node was found for property 'InputArguments' when reading from the JSON reader. A 'PrimitiveValue' node was expected

Tags: c#, json, rest-client, uipath

I am using RestClient to pass JSON paramter into api in C#.But I am getting response

> "An unexpected 'StartObject' node was found for property named
>   'InputArguments' when reading from the JSON reader. A 'PrimitiveValue'
>   node was expected"

I am using below code in C#

```
var client_startRobot = new RestClient("https://xxxx.xxxx.com/odata/Jobs/UiPath.Server.Configuration.OData.StartJobs");
var request_startRobot = new RestRequest(Method.POST) ;
request_startRobot.AddParameter("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer " + result), ParameterType.HttpHeader);
request_startRobot.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
string parameter = "{\"startInfo\":{\"ReleaseKey\": \"ds32rd1-6c98-42f542d-23bb8111ac91d\",\"RobotIds\": [1],\"JobsCount\": 0,\"Strategy\": \"Specific\",\"InputArguments\": {\"add_name\": \"xxxxx-xxx-\"}}}";
request_startRobot.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", parameter, ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response_startRobot = client_startRobot.Execute(request_startRobot);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a question of reading the API documentation carefully. Assuming you are trying to call an orchestrator as described [here](https://postman.uipath.rocks/), I find this example that looks a lot like yours.

```
{ "startInfo":
   { "ReleaseKey": "5b754c63-5d1a-4c37-bb9b-74b69e4934bf",
     "Strategy": "Specific",
     "RobotIds": [ 1553 ],
     "NoOfRobots": 0,
     "Source": "Manual",
     "InputArguments": "{\"message\":\"Aloha\"}"
   } 
}
```

Note that the InputArguments value is actually a simple string, *not* actual JSON (the string contains an escaped JSON string).

Your request looks like this:

```
"InputArguments": {"add_name": "xxxxx-xxx-"}
```

When according to the example given, it should look like this:

```
"InputArguments": "{\"add_name\": \"xxxxx-xxx-\"}"
```

It looks like you will have to "double escape" this part of your string, something like this:

```
\"InputArguments\": \"{\\\"add_name\\\": \\\"xxxxx-xxx-\\\"}\"
```

Actually building up a strongly typed request object and leaving the serialization to your REST client might make things easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error, and I had `regardingobjectid` propery, which I suspected it might have been caused the error, even though it seemed to be fine codding,

finally I relized that the problem was with another field

```cs
task["subject"] = data.subject;
```

`data` was `dynamic`, yet in logging it you got string value, but when assigning it you get a dynamic value. I fixed this line as following

```
task["subject"] = (string)data.subject
```

and the error disappeared :)